# Резьбовые соединения на python

Tags: python

Как можно на питоне рисовать резьбовые соединения, вообще можно ли? Знаю есть библиотека turtle, можно ли с помощью этой библиотеки, есть ли лучшая альтернатива?

Comment: Можно, если вы любите нестандартные развлечения. А вообще обычно для этого используют различные программы для проектирования, а не Python.

Comment: Если нужно схематичное резьбовое соединение (как на чертежах), то чем угодно можно рисовать. turtle - это просто надстройка над tkinter, изначально игрушка для детей для обучения программированию. Можно брать просто tkinter, создавать Canvas и рисовать. Если нужно детальное изображение (с витками спирали), то лучше действительно взять CAD программу.

Comment: @insolor в tkinter можно разве рисовать? А в pyqt5?

Comment: Да, можно, и там и там. В любой библиотеке GUI есть возможности рисования (как минимум на уровне простых фигур).

Comment: Вообще, нарисуйте в формате SVG (можно даже попробовать преобразовать в SVG готовый чертеж в векторном формате, если он есть), потом отобразите его в окне. Есть способы для этого и для tkinter, и для PyQt